# Debian update-rc.d command not found

Tags: bash, debian

I have seen some of the posts online where it says to navigate to the dir `/usr/sbin/` and look for the file `update-rc.d` but I'm still running into the error that the `bash: command not found`.

I'm trying to run: 
      `update-rc.d -f gdm3 defaults`

I've also tried:  `/usr/sbin/update-rc.d -f gdm3 defaults`

but that is still resulting in the same error.

please advise... thanks

Answer (score 8):

`/usr/sbin/update-rc.d` belongs to Debian package `sysv-rc` or `file-rc`, you should install one of them.

If you only know a file name and want to find out which package it belongs to, you can use the following command:

```
apt-file search file-name
```

To use it, you need to install package `apt-file` and update the local cache as instructed after you finished the installation.

Or you can search it online: [Search the contents of packages](http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages).

Answer (score 7):

`update-rc.d` can only be called by root, so try

```
sudo update-rc.d ...
```

or if you don't have sudo installed:

```
su root
update-rc.d ....
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had a problem with

```
$ sudo update–rc.d apache2 defaults
```

the hyphen between update and rc.d was picked up by ctrl-c from a web page. The same command

```
$ sudo update-rc.d apache2 defaults
```

when typed in directly ran OK. I think the hyphen is a printer's special character, not a keyboard-typed hyphen.